# Rescale a Pyspark Dataframe to fill a Certain Timespan

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark df with a following structure

```
Date      Name   Tasks  
01-03-20  Bob    3
01-04-20  Bob    2 
01-06-20  Bob    9
01-02-20  Alice  7
01-03-20  Alice  5 
01-04-20  Alice  4
..    ..  ..  ..
```

The Date format is in `M-D-Y`. I try to scale this dataframe based on the date-column, so that it is scaled up to a given timeframe, and fill the missing dates with `0 Tasks` . E.g. for a timespan from `01-01-20` to `01-06-20`, I try to get this output:

```
Date      Name   Tasks  
01-01-20  Bob    0
01-02-20  Bob    0
01-03-20  Bob    3
01-04-20  Bob    2 
01-05-20  Bob    0
01-06-20  Bob    9
01-01-20  Alice  0
01-02-20  Alice  7
01-03-20  Alice  5 
01-04-20  Alice  4
01-05-20  Alice  0
01-06-20  Alice  0
..    ..  ..  ..
```

Therefore I have created a new timeframe based on the timespan, containing the dates and splitted the original df based on the name. Next, I merged it together, and filled up the NaNs with `0`, respectively the name, like

```
df_full = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)

for name in df.Name:
    _df = df[df['Name']==name]
    _df = df_date.join(_df, df_date.Date == _df.Date, how='left')
    _df['Name'] = _df['Name'].replace(float('nan'), name)
    _df['Tasks'] = _df['Tasks'].replace(float('nan'), 0)
    df_full = df_full.union(_df)
```

I know thats no perfect and pretty glued together, however I fail in getting a better solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Tried to solve this in scala, (shouldn't be a big change for python)

### 1. Load the data given

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |Date     | Name  | Tasks
        |01-03-20 | Bob   | 3
        |01-04-20 | Bob   | 2
        |01-06-20 | Bob   | 9
        |01-07-20 | Bob   | 9
        |01-02-20 | Alice | 7
        |01-03-20 | Alice | 5
        |01-04-20 | Alice | 4
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS1 = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df1 = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS1)
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()
    /**
      * +--------+-----+-----+
      * |Date    |Name |Tasks|
      * +--------+-----+-----+
      * |01-03-20|Bob  |3    |
      * |01-04-20|Bob  |2    |
      * |01-06-20|Bob  |9    |
      * |01-02-20|Alice|7    |
      * |01-03-20|Alice|5    |
      * |01-04-20|Alice|4    |
      * +--------+-----+-----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Tasks: integer (nullable = true)
      */
```

### 2. Process the data to fill the timespan given

```scala
   // Given timespan
    val startDate = "01-01-20" // MM-dd-yy
    val endDate = "01-06-20" // MM-dd-yy

    val df2 =
      df1.selectExpr("Name").distinct().selectExpr("Name as distinct_name",
        s"""
          |explode(sequence(
          |   to_date('$startDate', 'MM-dd-yy'),
          |   to_date('$endDate', 'MM-dd-yy'),
          |   interval 1 day
          |   )) as Date
        """.stripMargin)

     val processedDF =  df2.join(df1,
        df2("Date") === to_date(df1("Date"), "MM-dd-yy") && df2("distinct_name") === df1("Name"),
        "full")
      .select(coalesce(df2("distinct_name"), df1("Name")).as("Name"),
        coalesce(df2("Date"), to_date(df1("Date"), "MM-dd-yy")).as("Date"),
        coalesce($"Tasks", lit(0)).as("Tasks"))

    processedDF.orderBy($"Name".desc, $"Date").show(false)
    processedDF.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-----+----------+-----+
      * |Name |Date      |Tasks|
      * +-----+----------+-----+
      * |Bob  |2020-01-01|0    |
      * |Bob  |2020-01-02|0    |
      * |Bob  |2020-01-03|3    |
      * |Bob  |2020-01-04|2    |
      * |Bob  |2020-01-05|0    |
      * |Bob  |2020-01-06|9    |
      * |Bob  |2020-01-07|9    |
      * |Alice|2020-01-01|0    |
      * |Alice|2020-01-02|7    |
      * |Alice|2020-01-03|5    |
      * |Alice|2020-01-04|4    |
      * |Alice|2020-01-05|0    |
      * |Alice|2020-01-06|0    |
      * +-----+----------+-----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Date: date (nullable = true)
      * |-- Tasks: integer (nullable = false)
      */
```

**Some Explanation**

1. Get the distinct `Name` and compute the `Date` for given timespan (startDate and endDate), here interval is considered as `1 day`
2. Do a `full join` on `input dataframe` and dataframe generated in `step#1`
3. Assign `null`s properly using `coalesce`